# Pine Script: How to cancel order if not filled on bar after entry condition is met?

Tags: pine-script

Trying to use barssince function to cancel entry order.

Want it to cancel if not filled on same candle order is placed/on candle following entry condition being met. I can't understand why it does not work it seems so simple.

```
rp1 = close[1] >= open[1]

rp1p = highest(high,1)

plotshape(rp1, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)

if rp1 and strategy.opentrades == 0 
    
    strategy.entry("RP", strategy.long, stop=rp1p)
    
    strategy.cancel("RP", when = barssince(rp1 and strategy.opentrades == 0) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Pine seems to have a limitation that **strategy.opentrades** is only changed when the entry is effectively performed.

Initially, I tried to use the following code to cancel my entry not filled:

```
candlesToEntrytInput = input.int(defval=3, title="Limit in candles to trigger")

longConditionWasMet = <enter the rule for trading signal here>
targetPrice = <enter the entry price here>

entryID = "Entry:\n" + str.tostring(bar_index)

strategy.entry(entryID, strategy.long, stop=targetPrice, when=longConditionWasMet)

for tradeNumber = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    tradeEntryID  = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(tradeNumber)
    splitPosition = str.pos(tradeEntryID, ":")
    signalBar     = str.tonumber(str.substring(traderEntryID, splitPosition + 1))
    entryIsNoLongerValid = bar_index - signalBar == candlesToEntrytInput and strategy.opentrades.size(tradeNumber) == 0
    strategy.cancel(traderEntryID, when=entryIsNoLongerValid)
```

That approach didn't work either. So I tried another solution:

```
shouldCancelEntry = ta.barssince(longConditionWasMet) == candlesToEntrytInput and strategy.position_size == 0
strategy.cancel(entryID, when=shouldCancelEntry)
```

This second approach actually works. However, the problem is when two consecutive long signals occur, in which case the logic fails.

It would be nice if the **strategy.entry** statement had an parameter called ***thresholdInCandlesToEntry***. That would solve this issue.

I am working in a workaround in which I use a helper [array](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html) to control my signals against **strategy.opentrades**. I will share my solution once it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
// LONG strategy
var myLongOrders = array.new_int(0)
longtEntryID     = "Long Entry:\n" + str.tostring(bar_index)
longExitID       = "Long Exit:\n" + str.tostring(bar_index)
stopLossInLong   = <target to be defined>
takeProfitInLong = <target to be defined>

longEntryHasBeenMet = <enter your LONG condition here>

// Scheduling LONG entry
if longEntryHasBeenMet
    array.push(myLongOrders, bar_index)
    strategy.order(longtEntryID, strategy.long, stop=high)
    strategy.exit(longExitID, longtEntryID, stop=stopLossInLong, limit=takeProfitInLong)

// In pine script, any order scheduled but not yet filled can be canceled.
// However, once a order is filled, the trade is only finished with use of close or exit functions.
// As scheduled orders are not stored in the strategy.opentrades array, manual control is required.
for myOrderIndex = 0 to (array.size(myLongOrders) == 0 ? na : array.size(myLongOrders) - 1)
    myLongOrder = array.get(myLongOrders, myOrderIndex)
    if bar_index - myLongOrder == thresholdForEntryInput
        longEntryID = "Long Entry:\n" + str.tostring(myLongOrder)
        strategy.cancel(longEntryID)
```

For more details, please see the script ***[J2S Backtest: 123-Stormer Strategy](https://www.tradingview.com/script/r7dHB8Ir-J2S-Backtest-123-Stormer-Strategy/)*** that I shared in the community.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys - which I have only just seen. I eventually got around problems like this using trade numbering, exit from entry commands with close_entries_rule = "ANY".